# Global variables inside functions value is NULL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpunit, global-variables

In my code I have a file that initializes a MySQLi class.

`File a`:

```
$db = new Database(); //MySQLi class
```

Anyways, there is a file that includes this database class.  That file also includes other files that has function declared in it. I'm using `global` to contact `$db`

`File b`:

```
function xy(){
   global $db;
   $sql = "..."
   return $db->getArray($sql);
}
```

`Testfile`:

```
require "file_a.php";
require "file_b.php";
require_once "PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php";

class testProblemStatistics extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  testArray(){
      $this->assertTrue(array_key_exists('xy', $this->xy())
  }
}
```

I get:
*Fatal error: Call to a member function getArray() on a non-object*

I investigated:

```php
var_dump($db);
function xy(){
  global $db;
  var_dump($db);
  ...
}
```

The first dump gave me the **MySQLi object**,
the second dump gave me **NULL**

Something is wrong with the global variable in file_b.

Additional Information: I'm using PHPUnit and I'm running it in the command prompt. In a normal browser everything works fine.

Comment: Where and when is the $db global setup in your tests ?

Comment: The $db is not inside of the Test itself, its inside of the file that has to be tested.

Comment: **and** when is it initialized ? :) anyway, did you try my answer ?

Comment: I tried your answer, yes =P But I still get the same error =/ I'll try to edit my question again to make the includes of the files more clear.

Comment: With disable backupGlobals and even with the blacklist, my Global is still **NULL**

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not more clear at all. You should isolate your problem a small test case like i did. That will answer the **when** is your $db global set up (how many times do I have to ask that ?)

Comment: Check the question again. I'm not using the global in the test at all. It is only beeing used in files that are included. Therefor I can't make changes on PHPUnits global backup behavior.

Comment: Are included **when** ? If a global variable works in your browser, but not in PHPUnit, it's because PHPUnit messes with it. I don't know how to make it clearer ... sorry. Please, post some code so that we can reproduce the error. I think I've used enough time trying to guess your problem and we both know where's that brought us now - nowhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [global variables are null when using PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073144/global-variables-are-null-when-using-phpunit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Solution is to hardcode the Database Class into the `$GLOBALS` Array.

```
$GLOBALS['db'] = $db;
```

Adding this as a PHPUnit bootstrap worked fine for me. It is kind of hacky and should be used in Test cases.

Answer (score 4):

You must fully understand PHPUnit's manual [on Global State](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.global-state):

> By default, PHPUnit runs your tests in a way where changes to global
>   and super-global variables ($GLOBALS, $_ENV, $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE,
>   $_SERVER, $_FILES, $_REQUEST) do not affect other tests. Optionally,
>   this isolation can be extended to static attributes of classes.

Very likely, the $db global variable is created during a test. Thus, it is erased back to null after the test. You could either set the global variable in setUp(), either manage yourself how you want PHPUnit to behave with this global. There are several ways to do that.

Switch the value of [@backupGlobals](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.backupGlobals) and it won't do the backup/restore operation between tests:

```
<?php

function xy(  ) {
    global $foo;
    var_dump( $foo ); 
    return $foo;
}

/**
 * @backupGlobals disabled
 */
class someTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testA(  ) {
        global $foo;
        $foo = 'bar';
    }  

    public function testB(  ) {
        global $foo;
        $this->assertEquals( $foo, 'bar' ); 
    }  
}
```

Do you understand why `@backupGlobals enabled` make the test fail wheras `@backupGlobals disabled` make it pass ?

If you want backup/restore of the global variables except for $db, define such a class attribute:

```
protected $backupGlobalsBlacklist = array( 'db' );
```

This works too. Actually that would be even better since it's nice to have test isolation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when run in PHPUnit, the top-level code in file a is run inside some method and the assignment to $db refers to a local variable. Make it explicitely global so that it stays that way in the test run:

```
global $db;
$db = new Database(); //MySQLi class
```