# Access a global variable in a PHP function

Tags: php, scope

According to the most programming languages scope rules, I can access variables that are defined outside of functions inside them, but why doesn't this code work?

```
<?php
    $data = 'My data';

    function menugen() {
        echo "[" . $data . "]";
    }

    menugen();
?>
```

The output is `[]`.

Comment: Don't treat it as global, pass it to the function as an argument

Comment: Where does the manual say such things?

Comment: Related reading: [PHP global in functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5166087/1409082)

Comment: Check the second example in this page : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: afaik we can access using $GLOBALS['varname'] where the index "varname" is  $varname outside the function.Infact we can use print_r($GLOBALS) to view all the global variables.

Comment: @MarkBaker Not always the best approach. Consider a simple script with a few loose functions and some shared variables outside of them. Changing how your functions work or putting everything in classes and using `$this->foo` can be overkill.

Comment: @MarkBaker My pet peeve is that when an asker want to do X, people reply "don't do X" instead of answering the question. when the asker decides to do X, we should presume innocence and think that the asker has been thinking this thoroughly.

Comment: Largely related to: [Callback function using variables calculated outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4588714/2943403)

Comment: If you're using PHPUnit, see [global variables are null when using PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073144/global-variables-are-null-when-using-phpunit).

Answer (score 205, accepted):

To address the question as asked, it is not working because you need to declare which global variables you'll be accessing in the function itself:

```
$data = 'My data';

function menugen() {
    global $data; // <-- Add this line

    echo "[" . $data . "]";
}

menugen();
```

Otherwise you can access it as `$GLOBALS['data']`, see *[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)*.

Even if a little off-topic, I would suggest you **avoid using globals at all** and prefer passing data as parameters.

In this case, the above code look like this:

```
$data = 'My data';

function menugen($data) { // <-- Declare the parameter
    echo "[" . $data . "]";
}

menugen($data); // <-- And pass it at call time
```

Comment: Thanks , You are right but they didn't use this line in the second example of manual :http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: In fact that second example was there to show the readers what **not** to do: `This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.`

Answer (score 23):

You can do one of the following:

```
<?php
    $data = 'My data';

    function menugen() {
        global $data;
        echo "[" . $data . "]";
    }

    menugen();
```

Or

```
<?php
    $data = 'My data';

    function menugen() {
        echo "[" . $GLOBALS['data'] . "]";
    }

    menugen();
```

That being said, overuse of globals can lead to some poor code. It is usually better to pass in what you need. For example, instead of referencing a global database object you should pass in a handle to the database and act upon that. This is called [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It makes your life a lot easier when you implement automated testing (which you should).

Answer (score 19):

Another way to do it:

```php
<?php

$data = 'My data';

$menugen = function() use ($data) {

    echo "[".$data."]";
};

$menugen();
```

As of PHP 5.3.0 we have anonymous functions support that can create closures. A closure can access the variable which is created outside of its scope.

In the example, the closure is able to access `$data` because it was declared in the `use` clause.

Comment: This was the only working solution in my case, where I had a function defined as a variable inside another function. Global didn't work there.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what does this "use" thingy do? What PHP versions are this "use" thingy supported in? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35233003/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate). Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Don't know why the approved ans doesn't show any output in Wordpress admin plugin page but this ans does work well.

Comment: This is useful to see, but one issue with this is that `$menugen` now becomes a global, so if you need to call it from another function, you're back to having to use the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 13):

It's a matter of scope. In short, global variables should be avoided *so*:

You either need to pass it as a parameter:

```
$data = 'My data';

function menugen($data)
{
    echo $data;
}
```

*Or* have it in a class and access it

```
class MyClass
{
    private $data = "";

    function menugen()
    {
        echo this->data;
    }

}
```

See @MatteoTassinari answer as well, as you can mark it as global to access it, but global variables are generally not required, so it would be wise to re-think your coding.

Comment: and another way is to use the keyword **global** (granted, this is not the best way).

Comment: "Should" doesn't answer the question, and this may not be the best approach for every case. For simple scripts, changing parameters around and adding classes is clunky. Much like JavaScript, in PHP not everything needs to be object-oriented and namespaced up the wazoo.

Comment: @Beejor Given that the OP has a function called `menugen()` it implies there is going to be more going than simply generating a menu. For instance, what about extending that menu to add more items from a different source, what about selecting the currently selected page that's in the menu. Having random global vars and logic all over the place screams for OOP design. The fact that PHP / JS doesn't need to be structured is one of the biggest reasons you find lots of messy clunky code. It can be done very well but allows people to have no thought about maintainability going forward.

Comment: p.s Down voting the answer is also a bit off. The answer does provide a solution to the OP's problem, just because you don't like it, doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: It may provide a solution for an implied problem, but doesn't really answer the original question, which was how to access a global variable in a function. And which is how people land on this page from web searches.

Comment: @Beejor - The problem with that argument is that people might *think* they need a global variable because they don't know any better and won't know any better unless they are told.

Answer (score 5):

For many years I have always used this format:

```php
<?php
    $data = "Hello";

    function sayHello(){
        echo $GLOBALS["data"];
    }

    sayHello();
?>
```

I find it straightforward and easy to follow. The $GLOBALS is how PHP lets you reference a global variable. If you have used things like $_SERVER, $_POST, etc. then you have reference a global variable without knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can be frustrating for this reason. The answers above using `global` did not work for me, and it took me awhile to figure out the proper use of `use`.

This is correct:

```
$functionName = function($stuff) use ($globalVar) {
 //do stuff
}
$output = $functionName($stuff);
$otherOutput = $functionName($otherStuff);
```

This is incorrect:

```
function functionName($stuff) use ($globalVar) {
 //do stuff
}
$output = functionName($stuff);
$otherOutput = functionName($otherStuff);
```

Using your specific example:

```
    $data = 'My data';

    $menugen = function() use ($data) {
        echo "[" . $data . "]";
    }

    $menugen();
```

Comment: This is basically a repost of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687471/6243352), but with a syntax error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected variable "$menugen" in test.php on line 8`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it only makes sense to pass the required data into the function's scope as a parameter. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/qGQmv)

```
$data = 'My data';
function menugen($arg) {
    echo "[" . $arg . "]";
}
menugen($data);
```

However, if your *actual* situation is more nuanced and you do not wish to follow the above advice, you can enjoy PHP7.4's arrow function syntax which allows inward-only access to values declared outside of the callback scope. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/A5T27)

```
$data = 'My data';
$menugen = fn() => "[$data]";
echo $menugen();
```

Or anonymously, you can [Immediately Invoke a Function Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403): [Demo](https://3v4l.org/UuaXr)

```
$data = 'My data';
echo (fn() => "[$data]")();
```

Comment: [Same comment as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687363/access-a-global-variable-in-a-php-function#comment136834609_35233003). `$menugen` becomes a global and can't be called from another function directly, so it sort of kicks the can down the road in most cases, since most function calls aren't happening in the global scope.

Comment: Okay, so the second snippet replaces the one global declaration with another. I don't disagree with that observation -- I was merely trying to be comprehensive in my demos. I don't personally declare functions as variables in my own projects. Lastly, citation is needed for "_most function calls aren't happening in the global scope_". PHP has developers doing all sorts of things -- it's the wild west. :)

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for this answer, sort of, I wanted to see if anyone else had something similar with respect to how `$prefix` would be passed to an anonymous function. Seems the global scope is the the way? This is my solution for prefixing an array in a non-destructive manner.

```
private function array_prefix($prefix, $arr) {
  $GLOBALS['prefix'] = $prefix;
  return array_map(
    function($ele) {
      return $GLOBALS['prefix'].$ele;
    },
    $arr
  );
}
```

Comment: This advice was given many years earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687471/2943403

Answer (score -1):

The proper way for accessing a global variable inside a function is answered above!

BUT if you do not want to use the `global` keyword, nor the `$GLOBALS` variable for some reason (*for example you have multiple functions and you are "tired" of writing `global $variable;` every time*), here is a workaround:

```php
$variable = 42;  // the global variable you want to access

// write a function which returns it
function getvar(){ 
    global $variable; 
    return $variable; 
}

//--------------

function func1()
{
    // use that getter function to get the global variable
    echo getvar();  // 42
}

function func2()
{
    echo getvar();  // 42
}
...
```

Comment: This is not exactly a good pattern--you still have a global, except now there's a layer of indirection to hide the evidence. If you're going to commit a crime, at least be transparent about it and use the `global` keyword as directly as possible in the function that breaks the "don't access globals" rule. That way, when things go wrong, it's easier to figure out the problem for yourself or other devs. If you're tired of writing `global`, it's time to reorganize the code rather than bury the problem. if you don't have time to reorganize the code, keep writing `global` to keep yourself honest.

Comment: With a single integer 42, no big deal, it's copied and basically read-only, but if `$variable` becomes an object, then there's a problem, the potential for mutating globals willy-nilly.

Answer (score -2):

```php
<?php

    $data = 'My data';

    $menugen = function() use ($data) {

        echo "[ $data ]";
    };

    $menugen();
?>
```

You can also simplify

```
echo "[" . $data . "]"
```

to

```
echo "[$data]"
```

Comment: `echo "[" . $data . "]"` and `echo "[ $data ]"` are not the same (two extra spaces in the output for the latter).

Comment: This advice was given years earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233003/2943403