# Variable that should be in scope is not

Tags: php, scope

I'm using a `$debug` variable to control print statements in a function I'm testing. Even though `$debug` is declared and initialized to `true` at the same scope level as the function, it is being treated as `false` (or `undefined`, I guess) inside the function. Is my understanding of variable scope in PHP wrong? How do I fix this?

My actual code is much more complex, but the following is a minimal example which exhibits the same problem. For what it's worth, I'm running this on the command line with PHP 5.4.24 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

```
<?php

$debug = true;

function myFunction()
{

    if($debug) {
        echo "I'm debugging";
    } else {
        echo "I'm not debugging";
    }
}

myFunction();

?>
```

For me this function displays "I'm not debugging".

Comment: This is *basic* scope here. `$debug` is *not* in scope. Why do you think it is?

Comment: @JohnConde It is at the same level as the function itself. How is that not in scope?

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. Variables declared outside of a function are out of scope. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: You can globalize the debug variabele but that not a good practice. However, if you use classes then it will be accessible via $this->debug.

Comment: I see. So I have to include global inside the function itself. Sorry, I have read the documentation on this before and I guess I got it mixed up.

Comment: See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687363/php-access-global-variable-in-function/15687405#15687405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just use following code:

```
    <?php

    $debug = true;

    function myFunction($debug)
    {

        if($debug) {
            echo "I'm debugging";
        } else {
            echo "I'm not debugging";
        }
    }

    myFunction($debug);

    ?>
```

The function requires the parameter "$debug" to work with it. Welcome to php! :)

Comment: The actual function `myFunction` has many more parameters and I don't want to add `$debug` to the list. The global solution is what I needed in this instance. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Then write a getter / setter for this.. i know this this problem, and it's the most simple way to solve it..

Comment: I ended up using a global, but I think the solution of passing it as a parameter is the best one (best-practices-wise), so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$debug = true; is outside of the scope, try this instead:

```
<?php



function myFunction()
{

   $debug = true;

    if($debug) {
        echo "I'm debugging";
    } else {
        echo "I'm not debugging";
    }
}

myFunction();

?>
```

You could also use [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: At least, his case already have a global scope..

Comment: @Tyralcori He's not using global in his example, I'm not sure what you're talking about. It depends on what he wants to do. He could also pass the variable in function arguments.