# Pass global as parameter in user-defined function

Tags: php

Reading about passing variables to a user-defined function and it says you can access the variable outside the function using 'global' but going through an answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687363/php-access-global-variable-in-function), Matteo Tassinari suggests "avoid using globals at all and prefer passing as parameters"

This below is my index

```
<?php

$registry = new Registry(); <- need to pass this variable

$router->map('GET', '/', function ($controller = 'Home', $action = 'index') {

    if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
        $controller = new $controller();
        $controller->$action();
    } else {
        echo 'missing';
    }
});
```

and I need to access the variable `$registry` which can be done easily by appending global to it but I would want avoid it and pass it as a parameter.

How do I pass `$registry` as a parameter?.

Comment: Use `use` ... https://blog.dubbelboer.com/2012/04/07/php-use-keyword.html, http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165

Comment: Thank you ... How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `use ($registry)` to the function

```
$router->map('GET', '/', function ($controller = 'Home', $action = 'index') use($registry) {
```