# phpunit global resource type variable is being set to 0

Tags: phpunit, bootstrapping

I am unit testing a legacy php project. Its db connect is set globally so it can be used through the whole project. For phpunit test, I bootstrap the file which create the db connect, but my test files, that db connect's resource is set to int(0), I couldnt figure out why.

**xml config to bootstrap:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="_app.php">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="generic_suite">
        <file>./tests/user.test.php</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

**test file**

```
global $db; var_dump($db); //it works, contains everything
class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
public function testUser()
{
    global $db;var_dump($db);//resource type is set to 0, others work fine, why!
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [global veriables are null when using PHPUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073144/global-veriables-are-null-when-using-phpunit)

Comment: i found the reason from this [post](http://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&goto=482946&), it's because phpunit's backup by serializing vars but resource type cant be serialized!