# How to fix PHPUnit losing global variable value between consecutive test runs from the same class?

Tags: php, initialization, phpunit, bootstrapping

I have a global PHP variable `$dblink` that is initialized and kept alive for the duration the web application run.  However, when I run PHPUnit I get this error

```
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

Looking into it I discovered that `$dblink` (database connection object) is `NULL`.  Tuns out it loses value somewhere between first and second test inside the same class.

Here is my unit test class:

```
class LpTest extends Tests
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        global $dblink;
        var_dump($dblink);//EXISTS and is not NULL
    }

    function firstTest()
    {
        global $dblink;
        var_dump($dblink);//EXISTS and is not NULL
    }

    function secondTest()
    {
        global $dblink;
        var_dump($dblink); //is NULL <------------
    }
}
```

How I run it:

```
phpunit --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php test/LpTest.php
```

I believe this is a peculiarity of `PHPUnit`.  If I remove `firstTest` above, the `$dblink` inside `secondTest` becomes not NULL and is a valid database object.  Presumably because it is the *first* test to run and it is initialized differently.

What can this be?  Why does PHPUnit lose global variable value between runs?  How can I fix this to where it doesn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9073217/1675789

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073144/global-variables-are-null-when-using-phpunit

Comment: Where this $dblink variable is initialized? In bootstrap.php file?

Comment: `$dblink` is initialized in `bootstrap.php`

Comment: gontrollez and Suni:  those links seem to have worked for me, thanks