# PHPUnit database connection lost when have more than one test file

Tags: php, phpunit

I have two test files for PHPUnit (for two different classes).  The tests in both files connect to my database and insert/select data to test my logic.

When I have only one test file (it doesn't matter which one), all of the tests in that file pass.  When I have two test files, an error occurs in the second test file saying `mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`.

Both test files start with this line to connect to the database:

```
 include 'database.php';  //connects to the database, declares $myDb
```

Both test files then call another class, which uses `global $myDb;`.

I am not sure why my database connection closes when two files exist- I do not close it anywhere.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us your classes?

Comment: The solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9073217/1532919